# Is there a more elegant way to conditionally access different properties of an object (Active Record) in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and trying to see if there is a better way to accomplish the code snippet below. I just want to throw on an extra level of filtering based on a conditional param defined elsewhere. This works but if there's a better way I'd prefer it.

```
groups = context[:active_only].present? ? object.groups.active : object.groups
groups.map do |group|
  {
    id: group.id,
    name: group.name
  }
end
```

Comment: is groups an active record relation?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Comment: You can define parametrized scopes for `Group`, but I'd say a better way is just to abstract out all the filtering logic into a separate class that will handle all the conditional filtering.